# Connecting phototriac substrate to adjacent pins

Tags: opto-isolator, triac, semiconductors

For a regulatory exercise I am analyzing the result of a short fault between a phototriac's substrate ([MOC3023](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MOC3023M-D.PDF)) and its anodes (one at a time).  The datasheet warns `DO NOT CONNECT` but what is the result of this fault?  Where is this pin connected on the TRIAC structure?

[image: TRIAC structure]

I am using this device to trigger a discrete TRIAC much like Figure 12 in the datasheet:

[image: Application circuit]

**EDIT:** Here is ON Semiconductor's response to my question regarding this pin:

> In response to your question the Pin 5 must be left unconnected in application. It is connected to detector die`s substrate. This is mentioned in data figure 1 (see the attached picture). It does not affect the insulation property between input side (LED) and output side (triac driver) of the optocoupler. However, connecting pin 5 to either pin 4 or pin 6 may cause the detector side to behave differently such as being falsely triggered on. Therefore, pin 5 must be left unconnected.

The attached picture was simply Figure 1 of the datasheet with a green box around the `DO NOT CONNECT` note.

Comment: I found your question while [asking mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/503870/19375). Regarding "Where is this pin connected on the TRIAC structure?" I think the "substrate" here is the base silicon layer. Focusing on the first picture in your question, I think it would be best depicted by the gray area of the background. Anyways, it's been some time and nobody answered. Did you find the answer? If so, please consider answering your own question and sharing the knowledge!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Looks like you had a bit more luck with your question!  I did not find an answer specifically; I did receive an answer from ON Semiconductor, but it wasn't much more than, "Don't connect this to anything -- it could cause spurious triggering."

Comment: It's nice to hear -something- from the manufacturer. Looking now at the second image DaveTweed added to his answer in my question, it's pretty clear that it's actually silicon substrate (the thyristor die rests on that leg!) so adding any voltages/currents to that leg could easily affect P/N balances inside the die, cause some unnatural bias here or there, and well, it's a thyristor, so probably trigger it or block it from triggering maybe? Anyways, thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With onsemi's response and Dave Tweed's [explanation of the lead frame geometry](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/503877/122929), I will call this question sufficiently answered.  In summary:

- What is the result of this fault?  **Possible spurious triggering of the optotriac.**
- Where is this pin connected on the TRIAC structure?  **Possibly on the base silicon layer.**