# Why "substrate" is exposed through a "do not connect" pin at all?

Tags: opto-isolator, semiconductors, triac

I've were reading through [MOC3041](https://www.laro.com.pl/pdf/moc3041.pdf) opto-isolated triac when I noticed this part:

[image]

"Substrate". It's also repeated later on one page down further, but there's no explanation. I guess that might be the silicon substrate upon which the device was build, and I can imagine that actually connecting it to a wrong thing could make things soon pretty bad. I also know that in discreet MOSFETs the substrate is very often tied to the source pin, so if the substrate here wasn't internally connected to anything for some reason, and even the datasheet says "do not connect", then it seems quite obvious to me, that, well, it should be left not connected. OK.

But if that's the case, then I guess that leaving it internally not connected would be the easiest and safest way, and I saw that a lot in various devices that had to be packed in some standard casing that had too many pins.

Then why expose the substrate at all and then instruct designers to leave it floating?
What's the use for this?

I've also seen [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/478135/19375) for a similar device, it could shed some light, but unfortunatelly it's unanswered.

Comment: Testing maybe??

Comment: *Possibly* left exposed for factory test purposes.

Comment: Thermal management? Probably not in this case though.

Comment: Or just because the part had to be physically mounted on the leadframe, and every part of the leadframe needs to connect to a framework during manufacturing.

Comment: Another possible reason is to radiate heat (the pin may make a handy heat sink).

Comment: @DGB I don't think optos dissipate that much heat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The back of the silicon chip (the substrate) needs to be physically mounted (soldered) to some part of the lead frame as part of the assembly process, before the wire bonding is done and the epoxy is molded around it. Leaving it unconnected is not an option.

Sometimes the substrate connection is brought out to the ends of the package, and then sheared off flush as part of the final trim after molding. Note the vertical rails that support the central chip platform in this 16-pin DIP lead frame.

[image: DIP lead frame]

([source](https://hackaday.com/2018/11/08/the-dual-in-line-package-and-how-it-got-that-way/))

However, in an optocoupler, chip platforms are required for both the LED and the triac circuit, and having this kind of central rail would probably compromise the amount of isolation that's possible. So they bring it out in both cases on an ordinary pin. This works for the LED, because that's how LEDs are constructed anyway. And it works for the triac because they didn't need that pin for anything else. Here's one example:

[image: optocoupler lead frame]

([source](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/optocouplers-working-characteristics-interfacing-application-circuits/))

Comment: Sounds very reasonable. The die cannot be 'floating around' when the epoxy is cast, and the lead frame is already there, everything fits. But why cutting the pin off "would probably compromise the amount of isolation that's possible"? It's metal. In the casing, between pins, it's metal-epoxy-metal-epoxy-metal, outside it's metal-air-metal-air-metal, removing the inner 'metal' and replacing it with epoxy or air shouldn't compromise the isolation? What am I missing in this train of thought? [btw.cutting that pin may increase costs or failure rate, so it may be a reason for leaving it as well]

Comment: It's a question of how much distance there can be between the metal associated with pins 1 and 2 and the metal associated with pins 4, 5 and 6 -- and the substrate. Remember, the LED chip needs to be physically mounted, too. Eliminating the struts running down the middle of the package greatly increases the available space.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that an opto-xxx would have a different "lead frame" (if it can be called that at all) than a typical IC. When I thought of the IC's internals I always had a mental-image of that typical frame like in the first picture, with metal rectangle in the center for the die to be placed on. Without them, and with the die(s) directly on the "legs", it's absolutely clear why the leg could not be "N/C internally", what leaves only the option of cutting the leg away, what in turn could be risky, as the die is not sitting comfy on a dedicated place. Thank you for that 2nd image!